# Плавная остановка потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Здравствуйте подскажите как правильно остановить потоки, если при завершение я останавливаю потоки данным кодом, я получаю исключение ThreadException и при этом, так как ошибка прерывания потоков, последние данные у меня не обрабатываются...
Метод  старта

```
void workStart()
        {
            LifeThread = true;
            ListThread.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread td = new Thread(work);
                ListThread.Add(td);
                td.Start();
            }
            btn_Start.Enabled = false;
            btn_Stop.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Рабочая функция

```
private void work()
    {
        while (User_Data.Count - 1 >= Log._index && LifeThread)
        {
         St();
        }
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Stop();
        });
    }
```

Метод остановки потоков

```
void Stop()
        {
            LifeThread = false;
            foreach (Thread thread in ListThread)
                thread.Abort();
            btn_Stop.Enabled = false;
            btn_Start.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("OFF Work", "Status");
        }
```

Comment: А что вы ожидали, используя `Abort`? Поток убивается, исключение выбрасывается, данные прекращают обрабатываться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я это понял, но если я использую  foreach (Thread thread in ListThread)
            {thread.Join();
                thread.Abort();
            } То форма виснет и не отвисает

Comment: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). И смотрите другие статьи по теме (ссылки слева в меню)

Comment: Не используйте `Abort`. Нигде и никогда. Забудьте об этом методе. Его нет.

Comment: `thread.Join()` - текущий поток будет ждать до тех пор (возможно, вечно), пока не завершится указанный поток. Читайте документацию, в конце концов.

Answer (score -1):

Вы *совершенно* не правильно завершаете потоки. Вы завершаете другие потоки внутри 1-го потока, учитывая этот сам поток. Используйте `Task` – целее будете.

```
static void Main()
{
    var task = RunTasks(5);

    task.Wait();
}
static Task RunTasks(int count)
{
    var tasks = new Task[count];
    var syncRoot = new object();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        tasks[i] = Run(tasks, i, syncRoot, cts);

    var task = Task.WhenAll(tasks); // аналогично `WhenAny`
    task.ContinueWith(t => cts.Dispose());

    return task;
}
static async Task Run(Task[] tasks, int id, object syncRoot, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    var parTask = Task.Run(() => { });
    await parTask;

    MessageBox.Show($"Task #{id} is running...");

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    try { await Task.Delay(id * 1000 + 1000, cancellationTokenSource.Token); } // some work
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }

    stopwatch.Stop();

    if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Task #{id} cancelled at {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show($"Task #{id} completed at {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) return;

        foreach (var task in tasks)
            if (task.Id != Task.CurrentId)
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Тут запускается 5 задач, когда 1 завершается, происходит отмена остальных. "Прямая отмена" заменена на отмену через `CancellationTokenSource`.

*Примечание: Не используйте `WhenAll`, если в этом нет необходимости: здесь этот метод используется в демонстративных целях.*

Comment: И где в вашем коде остановка потоков?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `Task.Wait` = `Thread.Join`. По результату

Comment: Повторяю вопрос: "Где тут остановка потоков?" Извне.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вы же сами писали: "Не используйте `Abort`"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov или я должен использовать `Interrupt`?

Comment: Верно. Но автору нужно останавливать потоки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ладно...))) вызов принят!

Comment: Повторю ссылку: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Comment: OK. Минусо-плюсомёт готов к бою. :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov всё

Comment: В методе `RunTasks` надо либо убрать `async`, либо добавить `await`.

Comment: @aepot да, забыл

Comment: @return ожидание выполнения не работает.

Comment: @ИванРудаков дико извиняюсь, нужно было `using var cts` -> `var cts` и в продолжении `WhenAll` нужно было его [`cts`] освободить. ответ исправлен